# How to dinamically choose the channel input for a listener method in @StreamListener

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

we are using Spring Cloud Stream with Kakfa binding and in our project we have envisaged the next two classes to implement a base consumer:

`MyConsumer ==> StreamConsumer`

Where StreamConsumer:

```
    public class StreamConsumer {

        @StreamListener(EventSink.INPUT0)
        public void handleMessages(Message<Notification> message) {
            handle(message); // here we call to consumer registered functions
        }
    }
```

```
As of doc @StreamListener:

Annotation that marks a method to be a listener to inputs declared via 
EnableBinding (e.g. channels).
```

And MyConsumer:

```
    @EnableBinding(EventSink.class)
    public class MyConsumer extends StreamConsumer {

        --we declare functional interfaces (to consume messages) to be register at StreamConsumer
          and managed by the handle function in order to be call back--
    }
```

```
As of doc, @EnableBinding:

Enables the binding of targets annotated with Input and Output to a broker,
according to the list of interfaces passed as value to the annotation.
```

EventSink interface:

```
    public interface EventSink {

        String INPUT0 = "input0";
        String INPUT1 = "input1";
        String INPUT2 = "input2";

        @Input(INPUT0)
        SubscribableChannel input0();

        @Input(INPUT1)
        SubscribableChannel input1();

        @Input(INPUT2)
        SubscribableChannel input2();   
    }
```

Application.yml:

```
      cloud:
        stream:
          bindings:
            input0:
              group: CommonConsumer
              destination: ${EXTERNALSERVICES_QUEUE:externalservices}
              binder: kafka
            input1:
              group: UpdaterConsumer
              destination: ${EXTERNALSERVICES_QUEUE:externalservices}
              binder: kafka
            input2:
              group: DeleterConsumer
              destination: ${EXTERNALSERVICES_QUEUE:externalservices}
              binder: kafka
          binders:
              kafka:
                type: kafka
                environment:
                  spring:
                    kafka:
                      brokers: ${KAFKA_HOST:127.0.0.1}
```

As you could see, the 3 inputs have the same destination because we want to have 3 (a dynamic number of them) consumers
in order to share the same channel but we don't want them to compete for the messages and so for we want to have
different groups (all messages will be distributed to all consumers)

Is there a way to declare in StreamConsumer base class a method to listen for messages with @StreamListener but
choosing dinamically the input? As far as I know, @StreamListener or @Input needs always a literal as parameter
(it could come from the EvenSink interface, a direct literal, an application property, an SPEL to manage partitions)

Or another possibility, are we able to dinamically change the group within the consumer?

I have also checked the option to obtain the consumer, as state in doc:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.0.RC4/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#pause-resume

but `Consumer` does not have access to group property. I guess that in the @StreamListener the binding is already stablished
and then the broker is up with a defined (maybe unmutable) group.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is content-based routing where message can be delegated to a particular listener, If so, you can use `condition` attribute on `StreamListener`. [Here is more details](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing)